# concern about using jquery offset function, and different screen resolution

Tags: jquery, css

If i use use jquery offset on a 1440x900 screen to see where a user clicked inside of a picture and place a box around the coordinace, will that box be in the same place with a user with 1366x768 resolution? If not, how can you satisfy all different user coordination with different size resolutions? Thanks for any help.

Comment: Why don't you try resizing your browser / changing your screens resolution and find out?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends on how you have placed the box on the screen. If it is floating on the page then the coordinates will defer. If it is fixed on the page then you will get the same coordinates no matter what screen resolution is. I hope this makes sense to you.

Comment: any answer will be a good answer based upon what I knew about this. thanks. Could you give a small example?